# Filter Get-GroupHierarchy output Powershell

Tags: powershell

Hi All I run the command

```
Get-GroupHierarchy "TEST" | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq 'Group'}
and the results are as below.
user : Test1
user : test2
group : Test subgroup 1
user : Test3
group : Test Subgroup 2
```

The issue is I cant get the `Get-GroupHierarchy command` to pipe and be filtered I have tried all sorts but it just wont output groups only. would be great if someone could help.

-Joe

Comment: Could you link to where you found `Get-GroupHierarchy`? On TechNet gallery?

Comment: The Get-GroupHierarchy command is not on technet, I just stumbled upon it, when trying to find out the Group Hierarchy under a certain group without the users

Comment: Well, then post the function definition - we won't be able to guess what a function that you "stumbled upon" happens to do